# share hibernate among 2 different projects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 projects:

1. Java EE - with Rest API
2. Pure Java using Java Scheduler that calls project 1.

In both I would like to use Hibernate.

Since the are using the same database, I would like to share the same Hibernate session

What is the way to do it?

**EDITED**

I want to use the same Hibernate cache! Not only the classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Hibernate Level 2 Cache (likne [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)). The L2 cache is responsible for caching records across multiple sessions but only for primary key lookups. If you want queries cache you can't do that with Hibernate when multipel sessions are being used.

You can make your own separate cache implementation (also using EhCache) and have some centralized way of signaling to it when it is dirtied by writes from a certain application.

Comment: Is it only for primary key look up? what for inserting data? will it cache it as well?

Answer (score 3):

Extract the entities, and potentially some common data access classes, in a jar, and use this jar in both applications.

Comment: See my edited question. I want to use the same cache! of course I know about jars..

Comment: Are you talking about the same second-level cache? If so, either have read-only entities only in your cache, or use short timeouts and accept some staleness, or use a clustered cache. Without knowing which cache you're using, it's hard to give better indications.

Comment: For now I don't use any cache. I understood that Hibernate provides first cache

Comment: Each Hibernate session had its own first-level cache. And each thread has its own session. A session is a short-lived, single-threaded, temporary object. The session (and thus its cache) typically only lasts for the duration of a transaction, and each transaction thus has its own. You have nothing to share between apps, except the classes of your entities.

Comment: So this is not good. I want to have cache like this: Each table is cached until save or update is invoked on the table. Is it already second cache?

Comment: You don't seem to grasp the way Hibernate works, and the concept of a transaction. Read the reference documentation. When an object is loaded from the database, it's kept in the first-level cache until the session is closed (which is also, most of the time, when the transaction commits). This is the normal and nominal way to use Hibernate. It ensures that if another transaction, in any other application, updates the database, Hibernate will see these changes. You shouldn't consider second-level cache if you don't fully understand how Hibernate and transactions work.

Comment: And even then, you should only consider using a second-level cache if you have measured that you had a performance problem, and that a second-level cache solves it. Hibernate is complex enough to use. It's even more complex with a second-level cache, especially if it must be clustered.

Comment: "It ensures that if another transaction, in any other application, updates the database, Hibernate will see these changes" how could hibernate see the changes made in db while it was caching the record?

Comment: The point is that it does only cache them for the duration (a few milliseconds) of the transaction. After that, the cache is cleared, and when it starts another transaction, is starts with an empty cache and thus reloads what it needs from the database.

Comment: what if in these few milliseconds the db was updated from my other application?

Comment: It doesn't matter much, because transactions run in isolation from the other transactions. Depending on the isolation level if the entity has already been loaded or not, you will or will not see the new value. Conflicts are solved using pessimistic locking or, preferrably, optimistic locking. This is described in the Hibernate reference documentation